# Fluent Validation MVC inject localization service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I want use Fluent Validation. I create validator, and want inject Localization service.

```
public class CreateUserDataModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateUserDataModel>
{
    private readonly ILocalizationService _localizationService;
    public CreateUserDataModelValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService)
    {
        _localizationService = localizationService;
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Tesfdf");
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("gfrfdgdrfg");
    }
}
```

How initialize service?

Comment: Do you already use a DI? If so, illustrate/share the related code.

Comment: Yes! Config [link] http://take.ms/GU7cR